# Trying to add time out from frontend in api gateway client

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, promise, aws-api-gateway

I was working with the amazon api client gateway. I have everything set up with the access key and other configs. And it works perfectly fine with all the request and response. Right now I am trying to add a time out for these calls from frontend, but could not get it working.

```
      var apigClient = apigCleint.newClient({
        apiKey: 'This-is-my-api-key'
      });

      var fn1 = apigClient.getMyData(params, body, additionalParams)

       fn1.then(function(result) {
            //succcess part
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }).timeout(1000, function(){
           //timeout part
        });
```

This is what I have tried, but the timeout part wont work. Any clue or suggestions?

Comment: you can check it [how to set timeout from frontend in apigClient aws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382717/how-to-set-timeout-from-frontend-in-apigclient-aws)

Comment: you can check it at [how to set timeout from frontend in apigClient aws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382717/how-to-set-timeout-from-frontend-in-apigclient-aws)

Answer (score 1):

it should be done as

```
fn1.timeout(1000)
   .then(function(result) {
        //succcess part
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

if promise timeouts then it will be rejected with TimeoutError.