# how to set timeout from frontend in apigClient aws

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, settimeout, aws-api-gateway

I'm working with the amazon api client gateway.it works fine with all the request and response. Now I want to add some timeout, I tried this:

---

```
        apigClient.method(params, body, additionalParams)
        .timeout(1000)
        .then(function (result) {
            //succcess part
        }).catch(function (err) {
            //error part
    });`
```

---

But It doest work. I got this message from my console
 "error: apigClient.method(...).timeout is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

The generated JS client doesn't support custom timeout by default, but you can add your own timeout logic on top of the client with very minimal modification since the underlying HTTP client is supporting client side timeout in the request object.

**Suggested modification**

```
diff --git a/apigClient.js b/apigClient.js
index 6f900b3..8977fb1 100755
--- a/apigClient.js
+++ b/apigClient.js
@@ -93,7 +93,8 @@ apigClientFactory.newClient = function (config) {
             path: pathComponent + uritemplate('/').expand(apiGateway.core.utils.parseParametersToObject(params, [])),
             headers: apiGateway.core.utils.parseParametersToObject(params, []),
             queryParams: apiGateway.core.utils.parseParametersToObject(params, ['test']),
-            body: body
+            body: body,
+            timout: 1000 // milliseconds
         };


diff --git a/lib/apiGatewayCore/simpleHttpClient.js b/lib/apiGatewayCore/simpleHttpClient.js
index 3fb1e5a..6a37a93 100755
--- a/lib/apiGatewayCore/simpleHttpClient.js
+++ b/lib/apiGatewayCore/simpleHttpClient.js
@@ -73,7 +73,8 @@ apiGateway.core.simpleHttpClientFactory.newClient = function (config) {
             method: verb,
             url: url,
             headers: headers,
-            data: body
+            data: body,
+            timeout: request.timeout
         };
         return axios(simpleHttpRequest);
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

I called to AWS support and I got this answer:

> Hello,
> Thanks for taking the timeout to chat with us!
>
> Here's a summary of our chat:
> You are looking fr a way to set timeouts while making requests to API gateway >from your apigClient SDK. Setting timeouts in API Gateway is not possible as API >Gateway has a hard limit of 30 seconds as a timeout for any type of integration. >For details on this, please refer:
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html
>
> However, automatic retries are implemented from the SDKs. For details on the >retry logic with exponential backoffs, please refer to the documentation:
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html
>
> Please get back to me if you have any questions and I'd be happy to assist you.

I hope this helps!!!

Comment: The limit of 30 seconds on the request from API Gateway to your integration endpoint, but you can have your own custom request timeout on your client like 1 second, 2 seconds, etc. Also, the automatic retries are not implemented in the API Gateway generated JS SDK for your API currently.